# How to expanding matplotlib figure in PyQt layout?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a ui file that has a QWidget whose child is QVBoxLayout. I can plot the figure in layot but it's size does not fit in that.

Here is my interface (selected one layout and its parent is a QWidget but it not seen clearly):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    layout = self._dlg.reservoirGraphics  # QVBoxLayout
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=transLineDict)
    static_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 7)))
    static_canvas.setParent(self._dlg.widgetRes)  # self._dlg.widgetRes is QWidget
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(static_canvas, self._dlg.widgetRes)
    layout.addWidget(static_canvas)
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
    self._static_ax_line = static_canvas.figure.subplots()
    self._static_ax_line.set_xticks(df.index)
    self._static_ax_line.set_xticklabels(df.Tarih)
    df.plot(x="Tarih", y=["Giriş Akımı", "Buharlaşma"], ax=self._static_ax_line)
    self._static_ax_line.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    self._static_ax_line.axes.get_xaxis().get_label().set_visible(False)
```

And here is my result. It is not fit in layout. It's view does not good for user.
[image]

And question is again how can I fit this figure in layout?

Comment: Could you post a complete example that runs, please?

Comment: It is hard to share full code that runs. There is ui.py file and others. It is not just a script